# Quotient Field of an Integral Domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

The question is:

> Let $n$ be a positive integer and let $D$ be the subset of all rational numbers of the form $$\frac{a}{n^k}$$ with $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $k$ any positive integer. Show that $D$ is an integral domain whose quotient field is isomorphic to the field of rational numbers."

So to show that it is an integral domain, I used the theorem that every subring of a field is an integral domain. As for the quotient field, I'm not sure I understand how exactly to find it. I thought it was just some $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $\frac{a}{n^k}\big/\frac{b}{n^k}$ is in $\mathbb{Q}$. Simplifying this would give $\frac{a}{b}$, which is the set rational numbers?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A general ratio of two elements looks like $(a/n^k) / (b/n^l)$—don't assume that $k=l$.  That said, the goal is to show that you get all rational numbers this way, so you should _start_ with a rational number, _then_ pick two elements of $D$ whose ratio is that rational number.

Comment: Is it possible to do this using induction? So for instance, assume n=1 and show that the result is a/b in Q. Then assume the case of n is true and show that n+1 is also true. Would this be sufficient to show that all rational numbers can be obtained using that general ratio?

Comment: I really doubt that induction is useful here, and it's especially not useful for showing that all rational numbers can be obtained this way, since there is no "$n$" associated to a rational number!  Let me put it this way: Pick some _actual_ numbers, and try to understand why their ratio is rational.  Now pick some _actual_ rational number, and try to understand why it can be written as a quotient of two elements of $D$.  You'll have a much better intuition if you know exactly how to write, say, the rational number $5/7$ as a quotient of two elements of $D$, if, say, $n=247$.